# imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in

Tags: php

Here is how I get my image:

```
$coverurl  = 'https://api.someurl/api/v1/img/' . $somenumber . '/l';
//$iheaders contains: 'Content-type' => 'image/jpeg'
$iresponse = wp_remote_get($coverurl, $iheaders);
$img = $iresponse['body'];
$testimg = base64_encode($img);
```

When I echo $testimg with an img-tag, everything works fine.

```
echo '<img class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single wp-post-image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$testimg.'" width="274" />';
```

Since I need to convert the string into a jpg and save it to my uploads folder, I tried to use `imagecreatefromstring()`.

```
$imgx = imagecreatefromstring($testimg);
        if ($imgx !== false) {
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($imgx);
            imagedestroy($imgx);
        } else {
            echo 'An error occurred.';
        }
```

But I never get to the point of saving anything, because of the following warning:

```
 Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in /etc.
```

When I echo `$testimg` I get:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD ...Many number and characters.. Ggm2JUsEvfqnxAhGFDP/9k=
```

What must I do to make `createimagefromstring` work? Do I have to modify the `$testimg` string? Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 9):

The method [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) does not take a base_64 encoded string. Try this instead:

```
$imgx = imagecreatefromstring($img); // Contents of $iresponse['body']
```

You can see this in the topmost comment in the documentation page (linked above):

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response; `$imgx = imagecreatefromstring($img);` displays gibberish: ����JFIF��

Comment: @timholz I dont think you should output the `$imgx` variable as that is just a image object. Instead try to create the jpeg file and store it. Then check what the content of the stored image is.

Comment: `imagejpeg` will output the image if you don't supply the second argument which is the path/name of the file to write to disk. But if you are sending out a content type header like that, it should convert to image (unless you have other output before this and you would be getting an output before header error) and likely see the binary source of the image.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment, I found the solution:

```
//get the image from internet
$coverurl  = 'https://api.someurl/api/v1/img/' . $somenumber . '/l';
$iresponse = wp_remote_get($coverurl, $iheaders);
$img = $iresponse['body'];
$directory = "/".date('Y')."/".date('m')."/";
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
//encode $img as with html image tag
$imgdata = base64_encode($img);
$filename = "gtb_". $isbnraw.".jpg";
$fileurl = "../wp-content/uploads".$directory.$filename;
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename($fileurl), null);
file_put_contents($fileurl, $img);
$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $fileurl ),
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($fileurl)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $fileurl, $post_id);
require_once('../wp-admin/includes/image.php');
// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $fileurl);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
//add media_category
wp_set_object_terms($attach_id, $mediacat, 'media_category');
```

This converts a base64 into a jpg and imports it into Wordpress plus attaches it to the post/product. It seems to work well. Thanks for your interest.