# Error: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am getting this error when I try to retrieve an image from the database, all I wanted to do is just print out the signature image in my view, can anyone help? I heard that the file might be corrupted or something or also it couldn't decode base64 yet I see them use encode on it? (quite confused on what to do) Thanks in advance

I saved my image into the database through user input and put it into the database in binary format. ($table->binary('signature'); )

Controller

```
    public function getInfo($id) {

      $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();

      $imageDataEncoded = DB::table('personal_infos')->select('signature')->get(); //get image
    $imageData = base64_decode($imageDataEncoded);
    $source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
    $imageSave = imagejpeg($source);
    imagedestroy($source);
     return view('test',compact('data','imageSave'));
}
```

view.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
<b>Signature: </b>{{$object->$imageSave}}<br><br>
```

If I remove this whole part at the controller and just used this in the view.blade.php, I won't get an error but I know it is wrong since I am supposed to convert it into an image which I had did. I saw from other forum that I need the path of the image but my image is stored in the database, so what am I supposed to do?

Controller (if remove)

```
$imageDataEncoded = DB::table('personal_infos')->select('signature')->get(); //get image
        $imageData = base64_decode($imageDataEncoded);
        $source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
        $imageSave = imagejpeg($source);
        imagedestroy($source);
```

view.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
<b>Signature: </b>{{base64_decode($object->$imageSave)}}<br><br>
```

Get signature image from user using this:
page1.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Signature Pad</title>
</head>
<body>

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'page1/submit']) !!}

<canvas id="signature-canvas" style="width:500px;height:200px;max-width:100%;border:1px #CCC solid;"></canvas>

<div id="signature-message"></div>

<div id="signature-buttons">
  <input type="button" id="clear-signature-btn" value="Clear"> 
  <input type="button" id="save-signature-btn" value="Save">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="signature" id="signature-data" value="">
```

SignatureController

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{

    $data = array();
    $data['signature'] = $request->signature;
```

Getting this now: (why am I getting this?)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228473/imagecreatefromstring-data-is-not-in-a-recognized-format-in)

Comment: It is somehow similar but I had tried fixing it using the answer that was provided. I have updated my questions could you help me take a look? @peterHaberkorn

Comment: show pls the sourcecode of the element that rendered in frontend and what is the base format that the user upload

Comment: @PeterHaberkorn I have updated my question to show how I get the image from the user. Am I getting this picture becoz I didn't put "$source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);            and 
    $imageSave = imagejpeg($source);" ? Becoz if I were to use those again I would get the error imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

Answer (score 0):

1. the foreach in the view is not nessesary if you use:

   `$data = personal_info::find($id);`

instead of

```
$data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
```

the following example shoulld work

you dont need the path you can use the base_64 string if he ist right formated

```
<img width="16" height="16" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhEAAQAMwAAPj7+FmhUYjNfGuxYY
DJdYTIeanOpT+DOTuANXi/bGOrWj6CONzv2sPjv2CmV1unU4zPgISg6DJnJ3ImTh8Mtbs00aNP1CZSGy0YqLEn47RgXW8amasW
7XWsmmvX2iuXiwAAAAAEAAQAAAFVyAgjmRpnihqGCkpDQPbGkNUOFk6DZqgHCNGg2T4QAQBoIiRSAwBE4VA4FACKgkB5NGReAS
FZEmxsQ0whPDi9BiACYQAInXhwOUtgCUQoORFCGt/g4QAIQA7">
```

the first "`data:image/gif;base64,`" is possibly nessesary but possibly not

try this:

```
Signature: <img width="16" height="16" src="{{base64_encode($data->signature)}}">
```

edit: you should really save the files on disk and not in the database

Comment: thank you for your reply, just asking this words "R0lGODdhEAAQAMwAAPj7+FmhUYjNfGuxYY..." are they all the base64 of the images? And where do I put it or is actually the "Signature: <img width="16" height="16" src="{{base64_encode($data->signature)}}">"?  Sorry for the dumb question, I just started this new part and is unsure of a lot of things

Comment: And another question why is it base64_encode and not decode? I am quite confused with that part

Comment: you put "Signature: <img width="16" height="16" src="{{base64_encode($data->signature)}}">" where @foreach ($data as $object) Signature: {{base64_decode($object->$imageSave)}} this was

Comment: I tried doing that but it just a plain picture (see question, I had updated to show what happen)